# When to add custom data to quote?

Tags: magento-1.7, quote

I have a code that is being passed in via the URL (akin to the Google source codes) that I want to add to the quote and order. I already have a function that triggers on the event `controller_front_init_routers` that adds the data to the session to pull out later, and I've added the field to both the quote and order tables. However, I'm not able to add the data to the quote at that point since the quote doesn't exist in the event. Which event would be the best time to add my code to the quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on if you need to take cart contents into consideration my suggestion is to put your custom data into quote using either `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` or `checkout_quote_init` event.

Then you can observe `sales_convert_quote_to_order` event and transfer your data from quote to order.

Comment: I agree on the collect totals - this is probably how I would handle it.

Comment: `checkout_quote_init` did it, thanks. No worries about totals, since it doesn't have any real bearing on the cart. It's just traffic tracking info. I already had the convert-to-order taken care of with the sales_convert_quote fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `checkout_quote_init` would be suitable for observing whenever a quote is initialized.

Other candidates - inspect the presence of the property on the quote from the session on any of these events - if it does not exist, add it:

**Cart add** - `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

**Cart update** - `checkout_cart_update_items_after`

**Item delete** - `sales_quote_remove_item`

You most likely want to consider **other points of entry**, though -- for instance when a quote is loaded because a registered customer has logged in - the quote is merged with items they may or may not have added to their guest cart.

**Customer login** - `customer_login`

**Before merge of guest cart** - `sales_quote_merge_before`

---

**More reading:**

You'll want to read this Magento.SE article regarding how to persist this information from the quote to the order:

[product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item/3810#3810)

Comment: Thanks, checkout_quote_init did it. I already had the code in config.xml to get the quote field to the order.