# Problem with product attribute attaching to quote/order item

Tags: attributes, orders, quote, product-attribute

I'm following this guide ([product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item/3810#3810)) however for whatever reason I seem unable to retrieve my attribute in my observer. My attribute I created is called "budgetcode" and is assigned to the product I'm trying to purchase. In my observer I'm attempting to use the same theory as the above post however my "budgetcode" attribute appears so deep within the schema I cannot retrieve it. I did `Zend_Debug::dump($item)` and can see a massive output (too big to paste) with my budgetcode shown way down, problem is I can't seem to retrieve it.

Observer.php

```
class Bendart_BudgetCode_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function setBudgetCodeAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        Zend_Debug::dump($item);
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $item->setBudgetCode($product->getBudgetCode());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bendart_BudgetCode>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bendart_BudgetCode>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <budgetcode>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </budgetcode>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
        </fieldsets>

        <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <budgetcode />
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>

        <events>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <Bendart_BudgetCode>
                        <class>Bendart_BudgetCode_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setBudgetCodeAttribute</method>
                    </Bendart_BudgetCode>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: if you cant paste the entire output of the debug, post something form the debug. The few lines surrounding the 'budgetcode' entry would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CamelCase is important in the magic getters/setters

You mention your attribute is called 'budgetcode' but you are using getBudgetCode() - which will translate to an attribute called budget_code.

If you attribute is called budgetcode then you need to use getBudgetcode()