# sales reports - directly to db

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, database

i would like to pull from database list of purchased items that within their description there is a specific *text*

the list of the items should contain the price they were sold at the time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will not be fool-proof; products stored in the catalog tables have fields such as `description` which you seem to want to key off of - however, as the information in the catalog itself can be **changed by admins it's feasible that the catalog information could change such that mapping to the sales table would no longer be possible**. For instance:

- A product is deleted from the catalog
- A SKU is changed
- The product has content in the description that no longer exists, but did at the time of purchase.

## SQL Join on the Catalog Tables from Sales:

Due to this I would say this approach is highly volatile, though @brenwpeterson's solution will work.  A more specific SQL query would be:

```
SELECT e.*,cpf.description FROM sales_flat_order_item e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 cpf ON (cpf.sku=e.sku)
WHERE e.increment_id="100000001"
AND cpf.description = "%your description%";
```

Please be advised that:

1. I'm using and assuming you have flat catalog enabled otherwise I'd have to assume what your attribute id's are. This can get complicated.
2. I am assuming this is your base store in the flat table (hence the table ending in `_1`) - substitute the store # of your choice here.
3. You'll need to replace the order increment id with your own.
4. The attribute `description` is not in the flat catalog by default, so you'll have to add it for the query to work. To do so, change the attribute to "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes" in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage`:

[image]

## The correct approach:

Taking the correct approach is beyond the bounds of this answer (submit a new question or sufficiently revise this one to describe your requirements) I will give you the high-level gist:

- Create a `description` field in the `sales_flat_order_item` table to capture the description at the time of purchase
- [Create a `quote_item` attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3812/336) that will save the product's description ot the quote item when added to cart
- Create an observer to save the information from the quote item to the order item on order completion

Answer (score 0):

This will give you name of item

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order_item where name like '%this is the example%';
```