# Pass custom attribute from product listing to cart page

Tags: custom-attributes, addtocart

I need to get a custom attribute from the product list page to the cart page.

I need to know how to send the attribute from the product page and then how to get that attribute for that product on the cart page.

Any help would be great.

Thanks 
S

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an attribute to the cart you need to transfer the attribute from the product entity to the quote_item how explained in this post

[product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item)

This because the magento cart items is a collection of quote_item objects

regards Giuseppe