# Adding a custom attribute to alternate admin (order detail view)

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes

I'm using SNM Mobile Admin to scan and add stock, and I've added a custom attribute called location_shelf, like this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="product[location_shelf]"><?php echo $this->__('Locatiecode') ?></label>
                         <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
            <input type="text" name="product[location_shelf]" id="product[location_shelf]" value="<?php echo $_product->getLocationShelf();?>"/>
        </div>
```

It shows perfectly when I scan a product.
Now I want to do the same with the order-details page, but it just doesn't show up. The only things that works is:

```
    <?php $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('location_shelf')

->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',32)
->getFirstItem();?>


 <p><?php echo $model->getLocationShelf();?>
</p>
```

It only shows one location ofcourse, but editing this piece always leads to an error.

The module's original order view code is based on  Mage_Sales_Model_Order
And uses `$_order = $this->getOrder();`
and

```
<?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection();?>
```

to get all the product info. Is there a way to show my custom attribute somewhere in here?

```
<?php echo $_item->getLocationShelf();?>
```

doesn't work unfortunately

The errors I get are like this: Call to a member function getLocationShelf() on a non-object

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Adding Custom Product Attribute To Quote And Order Items In Magento](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/) and [product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item)

The better way to do this is

1. Add the attribute field to your product
2. Add the attribute field to your `quote_item` and `order_item`
3. Add an observer that get and set the q`uote_item` from the product object when an item is added to cart
4. Clear your cache
5. Then you will be able to do `<?php echo $_item->getLocationShelf();?>`

Answer (score 0):

@R.S

Well, I just got it working with adding this to /app/design/adminhtml/default/snm-mobile/template/auit/madmin/orders/show.phtml:

```
<?php $skulocation = $_item->getSku(); ?> 
<?php $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') 
->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('location_shelf')
->addAttributeToFilter('sku',$skulocation) 
->getFirstItem();?>
```

and using

```
<h4><?php echo $this->__('Location')?></h4>
<p><?php echo $model->getLocationShelf();?>
```

underneath

```
<h4><?php echo $this->__('SKU')?></h4>
<p><?php echo $_item->getSku();?></p>
```

But I will try your method, I like to do this the right way.