# Used product attributes in order item

Tags: product-attribute

There do exist many questions about product attributes in order items. I hope my question has a new aspect.

If I have an order item I can use `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getProduct` to get the product:

```
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->getData('product')) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        $this->setProduct($product);
    }

    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

When we use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)` we have access to all product attributes and since the `getProduct()` method makes use of it I was quite surprised to see that I did not get all product attributes from this:

```
     foreach( $order->getAllItems() as $item ){
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        Mage::log($product->debug()); 
     }
```

My question is: 
Which part is responsible for setting the product data to an order item?

And how can I extend it?
My goal is to get the value of a custom boolean product attribute from an order in an observer after the order has been placed.

In the meantime I found the answer I was looking for (see answer below).
But if someone can explain to me why it is not sufficient to clear the cache but instead rebuild the index as well, I will gladly accept this as the answer.
It seems the info from the config.xml are written to an index table. Which table and what process is this?

Comment: Are you using flat product and does it work if you disable it?

Comment: No, look at my answer. But thanks :)

Comment: Ah crap, now that I see it, I've fought that battle before.

Answer (score 2):

> An order should be a "snapshot" of the items status at the moment the
>   order was placed and should NOT change as when that product attribute is updated.

Therefore a better way to accomplish this would to to add this field to your order item table.

See [product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item) and [Adding custom product attribute to quote and order items](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/)

Comment: Yes, you are correct principally. Product attributes should be fixed but in this case I want an info to be shown after the order was placed only once. An extra field in the database feels like a "too-big-solution". Anyways. I found the solution for my initial question. But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer to my question. It can be done using config.xml

```
<global>
   <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <my_custom_attribute/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

After adding this, not only the cache needs to be refreshed but the index needs to be rebuild, too.