# Export invoices with old price and special price Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

Is it possible to export invoices having these fields on exported file: Invoice number, Old price (total for old prices on invoice) and Special price (total for special price)?

I am interested in viewing the total discount for each invoice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you save the 'old price' in the sales order line items, moving that information from the quote to the sales order using instructions found here:

[product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item)

Next you will need to update your report ('products ordered'?) to pull through those extra columns. This involves adding a column to widget 'grid' or widget 'report' depending on what report you are pulling your data through to. I am sure you know the approaches to this - extending the built in report, having some event observer thing to add in the extra columns or writing your own report extension.

You can do some test orders and check the extra data makes it through to the sales order items table.

Note that you do not have historical data, so the report will only have your full price info for new orders.