# Magento Custom Field not storing in Database

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am using Delivery Date Extension in my website i need to add one more field on that so that i added below

**data.php**

```
 public function saveShippingArrivalDate($observer){

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('deliverydate/deliverydate_general/on_which_page')==2){
                $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::helper('deliverydate')->getFormatedDeliveryDateToSave(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('shipping_arrival_date'));
                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                    $order->setShippingArrivalComments(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('shipping_arrival_comments'));
                    $order->setShippingArrivalDate($desiredArrivalDate);
                }
            }else{
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
                $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::helper('deliverydate')->getFormatedDeliveryDateToSave($cart['shipping_arrival_date']);
                $shipping_arrival_comments = $cart['shipping_arrival_comments'];
                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                    $order->setShippingArrivalComments($shipping_arrival_comments);
                    $order->setShippingArrivalTime($shipping_arrival_time);
                    $order->setShippingArrivalDate($desiredArrivalDate);
                }
            }
        }
        public function saveShippingArrivalDateAdmin($observer){

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $cart = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
            $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::helper('deliverydate')->getFormatedDeliveryDateToSave($cart['shipping_arrival_date_display']);
            $shipping_arrival_comments = $cart['shipping_arrival_comments'];
            if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                $order->setShippingArrivalComments($shipping_arrival_comments);
                $order->setShippingArrivalTime($shipping_arrival_time);
                $order->setShippingArrivalDate($desiredArrivalDate);
            }

        }
```

**observer.php**

```
class Bc_Deliverydate_Model_Observer
    {               

        public function checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method($observer)
        {
            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('deliverydate/deliverydate_general/on_which_page')==1){
                $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
                $quote =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

                $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::helper('deliverydate')->getFormatedDeliveryDateToSave($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_date', ''));
                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                    $quote->setShippingArrivalDate($desiredArrivalDate);
                    $quote->setShippingArrivalComments($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_comments'));
                    $quote->setShippingArrivalTime($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_time'));
                    $quote->save();
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }


}
```

**phtml**

```
<dd>
    <ul style="border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1; margin-top: 12px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <li>
        <label for="page_date-end">Delivery Date:</label>
        <input name="shipping_arrival_date_display" id="shipping_arrival_date_display" value="" title="date" class=" input-text" style="width: 100px;" type="text"> <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin')?>adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif" alt="" class="v-middle" id="shipping_arrival_date_trig" title="Select Date" style=""> <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link_reset" style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ico_reset.png');?>" alt="" class="v-middle" title="Reset"></a>
        <input name="shipping_arrival_date" id="shipping_arrival_date" value="" onChange="shippingArrivalDateOnChange(this); return false;" title="date"  type="hidden"> 
    </li>
     <textarea cols="65" rows="8" name="shipping_arrival_time" id="shipping_arrival_time"></textarea>
    <li>
        <label for="shipping_arrival_comments">Delivery Comments:</label><br/>
        <textarea cols="65" rows="8" name="shipping_arrival_comments" id="shipping_arrival_comments"></textarea></li>
    <li>  <i><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('deliverydate/deliverydate_general/deliverydate_html'); ?></i>
    </li>
</dd>
```

**sql**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('deliverydate')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('deliverydate')} (
  `deliverydate_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `content` text NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deliverydate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote'), 'shipping_arrival_date', 'datetime');
$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote'), 'shipping_arrival_comments', 'text');
$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_order'), 'shipping_arrival_date', 'datetime');
$this->_conn->addColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_order'), 'shipping_arrival_comments', 'text');

$installer->endSetup();
```

also i create field in this tables
**sales_flat_quote**
**sales_flat_order**

filed name is **shipping_arrival_time**

my problem is it's not storing in Database what is the problem also shipping_arrival_comments also not storing comments working in local system but not in a live anything i need to do on this

i am using this extension [Link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-delivery-date.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [product attribute to quote item and order item](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you flush the Magento cache in `Cache Management`. Zend caches the table structures, so saving your new field won't work until this cache expires (or is flushed)

Comment: I tried but no luck